# Angular Custom Form Control validation works on form, but not with control.valid

Tags: angular, custom-controls

I'm trying to build a Custom Form Control in my Angular application due to some custom validation that I need. I took a working sample from Plunker, and I started to build on it. It is working fine within the HTML and the form itself: whenever it turns invalid, the `ng-invalid` class is added on the control, and when it's valid, the `ng-valid` class is added, and if I print the `form.valid` on the HTML, it prints it correctly . However, if I call the `control.valid` property within my typescript component, the control is always valid, and I can't understand why.

---

I made my own Plunker to exemplify this: 
[Sample Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/6xVdppNQoLcsXGMf7tph?p=preview)

---

I have a `<span>` that should appear when the control is invalid, and I check it in my `validarSpan()` function. However, looking at the `console.log`, `invalid` is always false, even when `ng-invalid` is clearly on the input control. I know that I could just check this, but the control.valid is used on all my other components for the normal controls, and it's dangerous to leave this not working. Is there a way to override the control.valid so I can return the correct information? I've been at it for more than a day now, and haven't gone anywhere. Thanks for any help